# Задача на JS "Танк и минное поле"

Tags: javascript

Необходимо использовать КОСТАНЫ вместо let. Для этого создать дополнительные переменные, чтобы они ориентировались на КОНСТАНТЫ, изменять их а не КОНСТАНТЫ. Переменную TANK_POSITION необходимо убрать и работать через  ROAD_MINES.length

if (mine == true) - нужно сократить выражение внутри скобок

```
const ROAD_MINES = [false, false, false, true, false, false, false, false, false, false];
let TANK_POSITION = -1;
let TANK_HEALTH_POINTS = 2;

for ( const mine of ROAD_MINES ) {
    console.log( `Танк переместился на ${++TANK_POSITION + 1}` );
    if (mine == true) {
        --TANK_HEALTH_POINTS;
        if(TANK_HEALTH_POINTS > 0) console.log( `Танк повреждён` );
        else {
         console.log( `Танк уничтожен` );
         break;
        };
    }
}
if(TANK_HEALTH_POINTS > 0 ) console.log( `Танк проехал минное поле` );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// const TANK_POSITION = -1;
const TANK_HEALTH_POINTS = 2;

for (const i = 0; i < ROAD_MINES.length; i++) {
    console.log( `Танк переместился на ${i + 1}` );
```